Flutter convert data into custom map with parent and child relation
I am working on a Flutter app where I need to generate a tree view from JSON data. The TreeView shown below:

The Table structured as follows:



ParentID
ChildID
Title




1
0
Root 1


2
0
Root 2


3
1
Node 1.1


4
3
Node 1.1.1


5
3
Node 1.1.2


5
1
Node 1.2


5
2
Node 2.1


5
2
Node 2.2



The JSON data is structured as follows:
[
  {
    "ParentID": 1,
    "ChildID": 0,
    "Title": "Root 1"
  },
  {
    "ParentID": 2,
    "ChildID": 0,
    "Title": "Root 2"
  },
  {
    "ParentID": 3,
    "ChildID": 1,
    "Title": "Node 1.1"
  },
  {
    "ParentID": 4,
    "ChildID": 3,
    "Title": "Node 1.1.1"
  },
  {
    "ParentID": 5,
    "ChildID": 3,
    "Title": "Node 1.1.2"
  },
  {
    "ParentID": 6,
    "ChildID": 1,
    "Title": "Node 1.2"
  },
  {
    "ParentID": 7,
    "ChildID": 2,
    "Title": "Node 2.1"
  },
  {
    "ParentID": 8,
    "ChildID": 2,
    "Title": "Node 2.2"
  }
]

This data represents a hierarchical structure where each node can have multiple children. The ParentID field indicates the parent node, and the ChildID field indicates the current node's position in the hierarchy.
Currently, I have hardcoded data to generate the tree view, as shown below:
  static const List<MyNode> roots = <MyNode>[
MyNode(
  title: 'Root 1',
  children: <MyNode>[
    MyNode(
      title: 'Node 1.1',
      children: <MyNode>[
        MyNode(title: 'Node 1.1.1'),
        MyNode(title: 'Node 1.1.2'),
      ],
    ),
    MyNode(title: 'Node 1.2'),
  ],
),
MyNode(
  title: 'Root 2',
  children: <MyNode>[
    MyNode(
      title: 'Node 2.1',
    ),
    MyNode(title: 'Node 2.2')
  ],
),];

What I would like to achieve is to dynamically generate this tree view from the JSON data retrieved from a database.
Could someone please help me convert this JSON data into a hierarchical tree view in Flutter? Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Have you tried to create custom tree node widget for your layout?

I am looking for help to convert my data to  custom tree node

I have added code for custom widget try if it helps.

To me, it seems like the json map you posted does not reflect the hierarchical structure shown in the treeview and the variable roots.  To make the approach of Marce work, you would have to make "ParentId" the node id, and "ChildId" the "ParentId".  In that case, for example, Node 2.2 has id: 8 and parentId: 2.

You only need a single function, one that can "convert this JSON data into a hierarchical tree", like this extension function.
As for guidance, I would recommend to convert json data into an class (immutable if posible). I'm using here an extension but only because the type is somewhat narrow.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const App());

final data = [
  {"ParentID": 1, "ChildID": 0, "Title": "Root 1"},
  {"ParentID": 2, "ChildID": 0, "Title": "Root 2"},
  {"ParentID": 3, "ChildID": 1, "Title": "Node 1.1"},
  {"ParentID": 4, "ChildID": 3, "Title": "Node 1.1.1"},
  {"ParentID": 5, "ChildID": 3, "Title": "Node 1.1.2"},
  {"ParentID": 6, "ChildID": 1, "Title": "Node 1.2"},
  {"ParentID": 7, "ChildID": 2, "Title": "Node 2.1"},
  {"ParentID": 8, "ChildID": 2, "Title": "Node 2.2"}
];

typedef NodeData = Map<String, Object>;
typedef NodePoint = MapEntry<NodeData, List<dynamic>?>;

extension NodeDataHelper on List<NodeData> {
  // Maps the a list of [NodeData] into a list of
  // [NodePoint] trees, nodes that don't have any
  // children have a null as a value to indicate so.
  List<NodePoint> as_tree_list() {
    assert(isNotEmpty);
    // Should you check if the data is malformed ?

    // In recursion, the child node is the parent node
    NodePoint _rec(NodeData node) {
      final children = where(
        (inode) => inode['ChildID'] == node['ParentID'],
      );

      return MapEntry(
        node,
        (children.isNotEmpty)
            ? children
                .map(
                  (child_node) => _rec(child_node),
                )
                .toList(growable: false) // Does this need sorting ?
            : null,
      );
    }

    return where(
      (inode) => inode['ChildID'] == 0,
    ).map(_rec).toList(growable: false);
  }
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: data
              .as_tree_list()
              .map(
                (tree) => TreeNode(node: tree),
              )
              .toList(growable: false),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TreeNode extends StatelessWidget {
  final NodePoint node;

  const TreeNode({super.key, required this.node});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget widget;
    if (node.value != null) {
      widget = Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(node.key['Title'].toString()),
          ...node.value!.map(
            (child) => TreeNode(node: child),
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      widget = Text(node.key['Title'].toString());
    }
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
      child: widget,
    );
  }
}

This example might seem a bit more convoluted but over all it's much better because converting json (a Map in this case) into a class removes all the lookups and thus making the code faster, but depending on how many fields the nodes have, the biggest benefit might be the type/value checks that class objects have (and you are getting lints from the lsp, the error are way more human readable).
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const App());

final data = [
  {"ParentID": 1, "ChildID": 0, "Title": "Root 1"},
  {"ParentID": 2, "ChildID": 0, "Title": "Root 2"},
  {"ParentID": 3, "ChildID": 1, "Title": "Node 1.1"},
  {"ParentID": 4, "ChildID": 3, "Title": "Node 1.1.1"},
  {"ParentID": 5, "ChildID": 3, "Title": "Node 1.1.2"},
  {"ParentID": 6, "ChildID": 1, "Title": "Node 1.2"},
  {"ParentID": 7, "ChildID": 2, "Title": "Node 2.1"},
  {"ParentID": 8, "ChildID": 2, "Title": "Node 2.2"}
];

typedef NodeData = Map<String, dynamic>;

class NodePoint {
  final String title;

  // Do you need this variables?
  //final int child_id;
  //final int parent_id;

  final List<NodePoint> children;

  const NodePoint._({
    required this.title,
    required this.children,
  });

  factory NodePoint.from_json(Map<String, dynamic> json_node, List<NodePoint> children) {
    // Do your checks here if you need to, any throw during this call should be
    // handled by the caller in order to drop bad nodes.

    return NodePoint._(
      title: json_node['Title'] as String,
      children: children,
    );
  }

  // Helper functions used while building the tree(s).
  static int _parent_id(NodeData data) => data['ParentID'] as int;
  static int _child_id(NodeData data) => data['ChildID'] as int;

  // Maps the a list of [NodeData] into a list of [NodePoint] trees,
  // nodes always contain a list of children that may be empty, use
  // [has_children] to check if a node has children.
  static List<NodePoint> nodes_from_json(String json) {
    final data = jsonDecode(json);
    assert(data is List, 'Not a list (${data.runtimeType}), wrong json?');

    // The casting needs to happen in "layers" and you may want to
    // type check all the variables like with the previous assert.
    final nodes = (data as List).map((e) => (e as NodeData));

    NodePoint _rec(NodeData node) => NodePoint.from_json(
        node,
        nodes
            .where(
              (inode) => _child_id(inode) == _parent_id(node),
            )
            .map(_rec)
            .toList(growable: false));

    // If the underlying functions are expected to throw,
    // make the return null-able.
    return nodes
        .where(
          (inode) => _child_id(inode) == 0,
        )
        .map(_rec)
        .toList(growable: false);
  }

  // Just for convenience

  bool get has_children => children.isNotEmpty;
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: NodePoint.nodes_from_json(jsonEncode(data))
              .map(
                (tree) => TreeNode(node: tree),
              )
              .toList(growable: false),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TreeNode extends StatelessWidget {
  final NodePoint node;

  const TreeNode({super.key, required this.node});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget widget;

    if (node.has_children) {
      widget = Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(node.title),
          ...node.children.map(
            (child) => TreeNode(node: child),
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      widget = Text(node.title);
    }

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
      child: widget,
    );
  }
}


your answer is very close to my requirement, the following code to convert from json to data =[ ]  failed , please see the code var jsonData1 = json.decode(jsondata.body);
for (var i in jsonData1) {
Treemodel treemodel =
Treemodel(ParentID: i["id"], ChildID: i["pid"], Title: i["name"]);
data.add(treemodel);
} saying type 'Treemodel' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, Object>'.

I tried  for (var i in jsonData1) {
data.add(i);
} also, but shows error Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, Object>'

I got it working by the following code, please advice me if it is good practice ? or is there a way I can add my model case directly to the tree view     for (var i in jsonData1) {
data.add({"ParentID": i["cid"], "ChildID": i["pid"], "Title": i["name"]});
}

Ideally you want to use a class instead of a json map, the second example comment adds a bit more context. Using the json map straight out of the decode is not inherently bad, depending on how rare the use case is, the complexity might not be worth it.

I have created tree node widget. Play with your required colors and properties.
class TreeNodeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyNode node;

  TreeNodeWidget({required this.node});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
      child: ExpansionTile(
        enabled: false,
        initiallyExpanded: true,
        showTrailingIcon: false,
        title: Text(
          node.title,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        children: node.children
            .map((childNode) => TreeNodeWidget(node: childNode))
            .toList(),
        tilePadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
        childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 32.0),
        iconColor: Colors.blue, // Customize the icon color
        collapsedIconColor: Colors.grey, // Customize the collapsed icon color
        backgroundColor: Colors.white, // Customize the background color
        expandedAlignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        expandedCrossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        textColor: Colors.black, // Customize the text color
        collapsedTextColor: Colors.black54, // Customize collapsed text color
      ),
    );
  }
}

And your listview as
ListView(
      children:
          roots.map((rootNode) => TreeNodeWidget(node: rootNode)).toList(),
    )

Hope it helps...

sorry, in this how do I convert my json data to the custom map?

Alright, let's break this down step by step.
First, you gonna need to define a model for the nodes in your tree structure. This is pretty straightforward. Here's how you can do it:
class MyNode {
  final int parentId;
  final int childId;
  final String title;
  List<MyNode> children;

  MyNode({
    required this.parentId,
    required this.childId,
    required this.title,
    this.children = const [],
  });
}

So, here we're just saying that each node in the tree has a parentId, a childId, and a title. The children property is a list of MyNode, which means each node can have its own children, making it hierarchical.
Next, you need to take your JSON data and turn it into a list of these nodes:
List<MyNode> parseJsonToNodes(List<Map<String, dynamic>> jsonData) {
  return jsonData.map((data) {
    return MyNode(
      parentId: data['ParentID'],
      childId: data['ChildID'],
      title: data['Title'],
    );
  }).toList();
}

This part is just mapping over your JSON and creating a list of MyNode objects from it. Pretty simple so far.
But, here's where it gets a bit tricky. You need to create a hierarchical structure, meaning each node knows who its children are. To do that, you create the tree like this:
List<MyNode> createTree(List<MyNode> nodes) {
  Map<int, MyNode> nodeMap = {for (var node in nodes) node.childId: node};

  List<MyNode> roots = [];

  for (var node in nodes) {
    if (node.parentId == 0) {
      roots.add(node);
    } else {
      nodeMap[node.parentId]?.children.add(node);
    }
  }

  return roots;
}

What’s happening here is that you're first creating a map where each node can be quickly accessed by its childId. Then, you loop through all the nodes. If a node has a parentId of 0, it means it's a root node, so you add it directly to your roots list. Otherwise, you find its parent in the map and add it as a child to that parent.
Finally, to display the tree, you use a widget like this:
class TreeNodeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyNode node;

  TreeNodeWidget({required this.node});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
      child: ExpansionTile(
        title: Text(node.title),
        children: node.children.map((child) => TreeNodeWidget(node: child)).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

And remember, always start by defining your entities and models before you dive into handling JSON data. This approach ensures you have a clear understanding of the structure you're working with, making your implementation much more robust and easier to maintain.

Your approach works, but I think the constructor of MyNode should be something like: MyNode({ required ... , List<MyNode> children = const [],}):children = List.of(children); .  Otherwise, the function parseJsonToNodes() creates nodes with a const children list resulting in an error when you try to add child nodes to an unmodifiable list in createTree().
